# Json {{@index}} for increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Am using {{@index}} to increment id for json.

However i wnt this index to start from 1 and then increment rather than starting from 0.

My code is :

```
<input type="text" id="demo_{{@index}}"/>
```

Now am getting the result like below:

```
<input type="text" id="demo_0"/>
<input type="text" id="demo_1"/>
<input type="text" id="demo_2"/>
```

I need the input in the below format:

```
<input type="text" id="demo_1"/>
<input type="text" id="demo_2"/>
<input type="text" id="demo_3"/>
```

So, I want {{@index}} to start increment from 1 rather than 0. How to do it???

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried it using increment operator.

Comment: Try `d="demo_{{@++index}}"`

Comment: Its not working Tushar..

Comment: I can't get you Praveen